# Get data from sqlite in XML format

Tags: c#, mysql, xml

I have an App which communicate to a MySQL database via webservice. The webservice serves the app with XML. Now I want to replace the MySQL database with a SQLite database. To avoid changing all logic I only need to get an XML format back from my SQLite database. To increase the level of problem, I have to read data from more than one table. Details of App: For each table I have the structure of my tables in class stored and this is the code I use currently which is not working:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myTableClass));
var sRe = new myTableClass();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
{
    xs.Serialize(writer, sRe);
    var buf = sww.ToString();
    return buf;
}
```

I expect a string of my XML in the variable `buf`, but when I run this code it just jump out on the first row. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: You are writing out an empty table, unless you actually *load* the table data in the constructor (bad idea). Where is the code that actually loads the data?

Comment: Ok I see, i would use following code to load the data:

TableQuery<myTableClass> tmplist;

But how to combine it now?